# Get subSet of set by using comparator

Tags: java, collections, subset, comparator

Is it possible to get subSet of collection filtering by some comparator and have every update on parent collection and its subsets get all changes?

Comment: Do you mean to add a sort of 'trigger' to your collection, which filters elements being added to your list?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to do for a regular collection, as the class would have to implement some sort of observable-interface. Either that, or you have to test all the element each time just in case something changed in the original collection.

Comment: Does `NavigableSet.subSet()` do what you want?

Comment: Do you mean filtering by some predicate, i.e. all strings that start with "Ab"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NavigableSet.subSet()` call might do what you want. `NavigableSet` is a sorted set that has the capability to create subsets that are "views" of the underlying set. These views are bounded by values that you provide, using the `Comparator` provided at the set's creation, or the values' natural order. The most common implementation is `TreeSet`. For example, you can do this:

```
    NavigableSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("b", "e", "a", "d", "c"));
    System.out.println(set);
```

The result is `[a, b, c, d, e]` as you'd expect. Now you can create a subset, for example from "b" through "d" inclusive:

```
    NavigableSet<String> set2 = set.subSet("b", true, "d", true);
    System.out.println(set2);
```

Here the output is `[b, c, d]`. Now if you add some elements to the original set that are both inside and outside of the bounds, the subset view changes to include only what's been added inside:

```
    set.add("a1");
    set.add("c1");
    set.add("e1");
    System.out.println(set2);
```

The output is `[b, c, c1, d]`.

Comment: Ok, and what I want is to create subSet not with providing from "b" to "d", but by some comparator i.e  subSet that select for me every second. I presume that selecting non continuous is tricky so there is no such generic contairner. But if TreeSet has i.e comparator that divide elements on i.e odd and even. I want subSet first part or second with use of that comparator.

Comment: @userbb OK, I don't think TreeSet's comparator can do what you want. The comparator establishes a *total order* of all elements in the set, and it's a fixed property of the set, established at creation time. You can't set it within a query operation, for example. It sounds like you need something more like a filter with a predicate, but I think you need to explain your use case in more detail. I and others are doing a fair bit of guessing.